# oauth for authentication end user using password flow

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth

Can OAuth be used for authentication (grand type - password flow) ??

I'm currently building a web application (microservices-based), and I want to implement OAuth for the authentication end-user, I choose to implement OAuth [password flow](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/), store the access token (JWT) in cookies, and validate that JWT token in the middleware.

After I do some research I found that OAuth is just for authorization, not authentication, is it correct? and how do I apply authentication with OAuth?

is the implementation of the OAuth password flow is not correct for my case?

Answer (score 0):

You first authenticate (with user-password input or with 3rd party apps like Google Login). Then, later on you can use OAuth wherever needed.

Comment: this is what I'm currently implementing, the user should input username and password in my website not with 3rd party apps. then i validate the token to identify the user

Comment: is there any problem if I implemented it like that?